# Avoid some functions/events to run when one function/events is clicked or executed

Tags: vb.net

im developing a system using vb.net and i have some question about datagridview function. Is it possible in gridview that when i click the rowheader function it will not execute the cell enter function of it?

Because my problem is in my cell enter event/function there is a code that will show some text box if the user enter on the 1st cell. and i want that when i click the row header of my grid view this cell enter event/function will not be executed. is it possible guys? give me some tips or tricks on how to do it.

i've also done trying like this

Private sub gridview_RowHeaderMouseClick . . .
    textbox.visible = false
    gridview.endEdit(true)
end sub

the result is okay but it is not good for the client view and i want to improve it more.

This is my code.

```
Private Sub dgCharges_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgCharges.CellEnter
 if e.ColumnIdex >= 0 Then
    if e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
      'Show Textbox.
    End If
 End if
End Sub

Private Sub dgCharges_RowHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dgCharges.RowHeaderMouseClick
 'Textbox.visible = false //this line i've use to hide the textbox when user
 clicked row header.
 dgCharges.EndEdit(True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a test in the CellEnter function that only executes the restricted part of the code if the column index >= 0. The header has index -1

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEnter
    If e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
        'Do my stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

------ EDIT ----

To prevent the datagridview cell editors from popping up just set the column to readonly. Alternatively for more control use

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewMsg.CellBeginEdit
    'Test your criteria
    If shouldBeReadonly Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i've tried this code but still not working. the row header still executing the cell enter event/funtion. maybe it is because of the effect of rowheader? when i click the rowheader event the entire row is selected but that is the defualt funtion of the row header. also i have two if inside my cellenter event. the 1st is the one you gave me and the 2nd is the specific index clicke. that is the index of 1st cell

Comment: I thought your problem was that your textbox was still showing when you clicked the row header. What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that is there any way to avoid the cellenter event. so that when user click row header the textbox will not show anymore unless if the user click the specific cell of the gridview

Comment: Ah, sorry. I understand now. You're not popping up a textbox, you're just trying to block the editing. Try setting the columns to readonly.